# c write the string to file line by line

Tags: c

fwrite don't work, what's wrong with my code?

```
void printTree (struct recordNode* tree) {
        char* report1;

        FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt","w");

        if (tree == NULL) {
          return;
        }
        //if(fp) {

          counter2++;
          printTree(tree->right);

          fwrite(fp,"%d\n", tree->pop);
          //putc(tree->pop, fp);

          //report1 = printf("%s = %d\n");
          printTree(tree->left);

        //}
        fclose(fp);

    }
```

Comment: I think you should use fprintf for formatted output to stream...

Comment: Try fprintf(), may be it works. Otherwise edit again

Comment: It will be very helpful for you to use the options for maximum warnings in your compiler. Pay attention to the warnings and fix every one. Any compiler would have informed you that this code is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fwrite` does not do formatted output like that, you need `fprintf`:

```
fprintf (fp, "%d\n", tree->pop);
```

`fwrite` has the following prototype:

```
size_t fwrite (const void *restrict buff,
               size_t               sz,
               size_t               num,
               FILE *restrict       hndl);
```

and, since you're not even *giving* it that all-important fourth parameter (the file handle) in your call, it can pretty well whatever it pleases.

A decent compiler should have warned you about this.

You also have another problem here. Each time you call this function, you create the output file anew. That's not good for a recursive function since each recurring call will destroy the information already written.

You may want to open the file *outside* of the recursive function and simply *use* it within there.

Something like:

```
static void printTreeRecur (FILE *fp, struct recordNode* tree) {
    if (tree == NULL) return;

    printTreeRecur (fp, tree->right);
    fprintf (fp, "%d\n", tree->pop);
    printTreeRecur (fp, tree->left);
}

void printTree (struct recordNode* tree) {
    FILE *fp = fopen ("test.txt", "w");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        printTreeRecur (fp, tree);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: who to use fprintf, will the following line work?
fprintf (fp, "%s", "%d\n", tree->district, tree->pop);

Comment: @hkvega: you want something like: `fprintf (fp, "%s %d\n", tree->district, tree->pop);`. When it comes to format strings, "there can be only one".

Comment: if i want to add "Report 1" to text file, how to do this?

Comment: @hkvega, if you want it on a line at the start, just `fprintf (fp, "Report 1\n");` before entering `printTreeRecur()`. If you want it in your regular lines, add it to the format string like: `fprintf (fp, "Report 1: %s %d\n", tree->district, tree->pop);`.

Comment: It's also possible to open the file in append-mode, although I would still recommend opening it once and then just re-using, it will be far more efficient and not risk running out of resources (file handles).